# How to add data in excel but the data the user input goes on the top of the table in flutter

Tags: excel, flutter

I want to add data into an excel file but the data I added must on the top of the column. I accomplished to add data below another data, but I want to add it above another data.

This is the program I made

`String filePath = 'Monitoring VCC dan RPT RCT_dummy.xlsx';
final File file = File(filePath);
final List? bytes = await file.readAsBytes();

```
if (bytes != null) {
  var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
  var sheet = excel['Sheet1'];

  if (sheet
          .cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 0, rowIndex: 1))
          .value !=
      null) {
    i++;
    sheet
        .cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 0, rowIndex: i))
        .value = nolapor;
  } else {
    sheet
        .cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 0, rowIndex: 1))
        .value = nolapor;
  }
```

var encode = excel.encode();
await file.writeAsBytes(encode!);

```
  file.writeAsBytes(excel.save()!);`
```

Any idea how to add another data above the data ?